# condition operator and arrays / returning an pointer to array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I was hoping someone could explain how the condition statement of `return (i % 2) ? &odd : &even;` is able to determine if `i` is even or odd.

I am confused because `&odd` and `&even` are references to `int odd[]` and `int even[]`. It is my understanding the a condition statement does not "iterate" through the array and check all values in the array in order to check the condition of `(i % 2)` for a match. below is the code. I hope I was clear enough.

```
#include <iostream>

int odd[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
int even[] = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 };

decltype(odd)* arrptr(int i) { // equivalent to int (*arrPtr(int))[5] or
                               // auto arrPtr(int i) -> int(*)[5]
    return (i % 2) ? &odd : &even;
}

int main()
{
    arrptr(3);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to explain the confusion you've as I see in the comments you posted to the other answer.

> How does the conditional statement know the difference between what is a even number or an odd number?

It doesn't. It simply evaluates the first expression and checks the truth value. Like an `if`, you insert the logic on deciding if `i` is even or odd. Usually this is done with the interger reminder operator `i % 2`.

> The expressions in the conditional statement are nothing more than references to an array named &odd[] and &even[]. There is nothing in the program that tells the program what even or odd number means.

No, the second and the third arguments are what `&odd[]` and `&even[]` are. You missed the first; it is a conditional expression which will be evaluated for a truth value.

`i % 2` will return `0` if `i` is even, else `1` if `i` is odd. This integer value will be implicitly converted into a boolean value since the expression is evaluated in a boolean context. In C and C++ any non-zero value is *true* else *false*. Hence if `i` is even it'll return *false*, else *true*.

I think what is confusing you is the name of operands 2 and 3; mentally rename them into `evenArray` and `oddArray`. What the operator does is, it returns an array. Which array? That it decides based on the first operand, which in turn decides it with parity (even/odd) of the argument `i`.

Comment: I think I get it. the `%` operator returns the remainder of a division. if there is no remainder, the result will be `0`, which in bool value is equivalent to `true`, any other result is `false`. Correct? if that is right my last bit of confusion would be this: a conditional statements logic goes as follows: `(condition) ? epres1 : expres2`  if `condition` is `true` we execute `expres1` else we execute `expres2`. if that is correct, with the expression of `return (i % 2) ? &odd : &even;` if `i` is even and the condition is `true` would that not point to `&odd` which is the wrong array?

Comment: _if there is no remainder, the result will be 0, which in bool value is equivalent to true, any other result is false. Correct?_ No, `0` is `int` equivalent of `bool`'s _false_.

Comment: _if `i` is even and the condition is true would that not point to &odd which is the wrong array?_ No. If `i` is even, `i % 2` will return 0 which implies _false_ and hence would return `&even`.

Answer (score 1):

That is the C conditional operator `?:`. The part before the question mark is a Boolean expression. If it evaluates to true then the part between the questions mark and the colon is executed otherwise the other part is executed. It's equivalent to:

```
if(boolean expr) { expression1 }
else             { expression2 }
```

In your example, you could write:

```
decltype(odd)* arrptr(int i)
{   if(i % 2) return &odd;
    else return &even;
}
```

You might be confused by how the arrays are named. The function returns a pointer to an array depending on the value of `i` (the function knows nothing about the numbers stored in the arrays). That is, if `i` is an odd number we return a pointer to the array named `odd` and if it `i` is even we return a pointer to the array named `even`. The `i % 2` part tells you if `i` is even or odd. Hope this helps.

Comment: Good now explain to the OP that it doesn't iterate through anything; only the function argument `i` is checked (by comparing it to `1` modulo `2`; look this up in your maths textbook but it really does just mean "is this integer odd?") and a pointer to the proper array is returned. The values in those arrays are not relevant.

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit, you stated "...but it does just mean "is this integer odd?...". How does the conditional statement know the difference between what is a even number or an odd number? The expressions in the conditional statement are nothing more than references to an array named `&odd[]` and `&even[]`. There is nothing in the program that tells the program what even or odd number means. I am trying to understand how/what tells the program how to tell if the result of `(i % 2)` is a even or odd number, and how does it know to return a pointer to the correct array?